# Why does my while loop execute even though condition is not true?

Tags: c#

Im coding a simple program too convert celsius to fahrenheit. To pick if you want to convert celsius to fahrenheit or the other way around you enter 1 or 2 into the console. Therefor I wrote a while loop that I want to get executed until you enter either 1 or 2 into the console. Instead the loop continues no matter if the input is correct or not.

```
int x, y, method;
Console.WriteLine("Ange '1' för C to F. Ange '2' för F to C");
method = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

while (method != 1 || method != 2)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Ingen giltig metod valdes, välj giltid metod (1, 2)");
    method = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
}
if (method == 1 || method == 2)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Ange temperatur som motsavarar metoden");
    x = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

    if (method == 1)
    {
        y = x * 9 / 5 + 32;
        Console.WriteLine("Temperaturen {0}C blir {1}F", x, y);
        Console.Read();
    }
    else if (method == 2)
    {
        y = (x - 32) * 5 / 9;
        Console.WriteLine("Temperaturen {0}F blir {1}C", x, y);
        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

I expect the while loop too execute until the value is either 1 or 2. When the varible "method" equals to either 1 or 2 I want the if statment below to run. Instead of the while loop continuing no matter input.

Comment: You need to use `&&`, not `||` in the `while` loop.

Comment: `while (method != 1 || method != 2)` translated in English means: "_(loop) as long as method is not 1 **OR** method is not 2_". Since `method` cannot be 1 and 2 at the same time at once, `method` will **always** be either not 1 or not 2, which again translates to "_loop always/forever_"...

Comment: As an aside, once you've fixed it you **know** that `method` is `1` or`2` so you don't need the `if`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to `and` those conditions instead of `or`:

```
while (method != 1 && method != 2)
```

for further development word your requirements using word `while` so instead of:

```
I expect the while loop too execute until the value is either 1 or 2
```

you should say to yourself

```
I expect the loop to execute while value is not equal to 1 and is not equal to 2
```

Answer (score 0):

If you write `1` to your console then the condition `method != 1 || method != 2` can be read as `1 != 1 || 1 != 2` or `false || true` or just `true`.

You need to change your condition to `while(method != 1 && method != 2)` that can read as `method is not 1 AND method is not 2`.